# X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response in Wordpress wp-json

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, http-headers

I have a Wordpress blog site installed in a sub folder in my root directory and a static single page site hosted in the same root directory. Now I am trying to get the blogs in my static site by JQuery AJAX calls from wp-json rest api. But the server is responding with the following error message:

> Failed to load https://example.com/rest/of/url: Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

I have installed a plugin to add the Headers in my WP blog site but its also not working. I am adding my JS code here as well.

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'https://example.com/rest/of/url',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
```

Can somebody help me with this issue.

Comment: Why is this cross-domain in the first place? From your description it sounds as if everything was available under the same origin to begin with. Have you tried simply using a relative URL in your AJAX request?

Comment: Thank you for your response @misorude. Yes I tried that. it worked in some browsers but not in all. I tried in different PCs and in different browsers and in most of the cases I faced that problem. Also got this error in incognito mode.